# getUserPrincipalLookupService on Mac/Linux for SMB

Tags: java, linux, macos, acl, smb

I am trying to change the owner of a directory on a SMB share using a Mac/Linux machine in Java. If I run the same programme from Windows it works...

The SMB share is from a windows server and mounted on my Mac but will be eventually mounted from a Linux server.

The problem is I can't get the Windows AD UserPrincipal from lookupPrincipalByName as it appears the getUserPrincipalLookupService uses the local system usernames as the only available usernames?

I can create the directory from the Mac and it inherits the ACL from it's parent on the windows server. but I can't change the ACL as I get java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException.

I think it may have something to do with SMB and how it is mounted with some kind of translation of username/id mapped from the local user to the mounted user?

(smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by stuart)

if so then is it possible to change windows ACL via SMB on Mac/Linux?